# How to find indices of specific rows in dataframe r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, A, which looks like this:

```
col 1   col2   col3
 NL      6       9
 UK      5       5
 US      9       7
```

and I have a dataframe, B, consisting of a subset of the rows of the large dataframe looking like this:

```
 col 1   col2   col3
 NL      6       9
 UK      5       5
```

Now, I want to find the indices of the rows from B in A, so it should return `1 and 2`. Does someone know how to do this?

EDIT
Next, I also want to find the indices of the rows in A, when I have only the first two columns in B. So, in that case it should also return `1 and 2`. Anyone an idea how to do this?

Comment: `match(do.call(paste, df2), do.call(paste, df1))` or do a `merge` and get he rownames

Comment: This results in a vector with only `NA` values in my case

Comment: then, it means the 'col 1', might have some leading/laggins spces

Comment: The result I get by copy/pasting your data is  `match(do.call(paste, df2), do.call(paste, df1))#
[1] 1 2`

Comment: My column names were indeed wrong, thanks! Do you maybe also have an idea on how to solve my edited part?

Comment: Then, subset the columns in two dataset, `match(do.call(paste, df2), do.call(paste, df1[1:2]))`

Comment: Great this works, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `match` gets the index.  In our case, an approach is to `paste` the rows together and get the index with `match`

```
match(do.call(paste, df2), do.call(paste, df1)
```

---

If there are only subset of columns that are having the same column  names, get the vector of column names with `intersect`, subset the datasets, do the `paste` and get the index with `match`

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
match(do.call(paste, df2[nm1]), do.call(paste, df1[nm1]))
```

---

Another option is `join` where we create a row index in both datasets, do a join and extract the row index

```
 library(dplyr)
 df2 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   left_join(df2 %>% 
          mutate(rn = row_number()), by = c('col1', 'col2', 'col3')) %>% 
   pull(rn.y)
```